# Can not figure out how checkout works in git

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, git-checkout

I have created a new repository and commited a file `a.pl`. All ok.
If I do `git status` that there is nothing added or untracked changes. I do a `git log` and I see the `hash` of my last (and actually only) commit in this repository.
Now I modify the `a.pl` and I append a new line in the end of the file. E.g `print "1";`
I save it and if I do `git status` it reports untracked changes.
Now If I do: `git checkout <commit_id>` using the hash reported in `git log` I expect to go to the version I commited, so my recent untracked modification should be deleted.
I do `git checkout 1d739` and I get:

> Note: checking out '1d739'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental   changes and commit them, and you can discard any
>   commits you make in this   state without impacting any branches by
>   performing another checkout. etc

When I look in the file, I see that the `print "1";` I added is still there!
Now in this checkout version I append another line in the file: `print "2";` and save the file.

Then I do: `git checkout master`. This would take me back to the latest commit, right? So I expected that the last append I did `print "2";` would be lost.
Well after I get: `Switched to branch 'master'` I see the file and it has both `print "1";` and `print "2";`.
This is really confusing. Shouldn't I be seeing the latest commit now? And both the modifications should be lost?

Answer (score 1):

Local, uncommitted changes are kept when you checkout different branches or commits.
Quoting [the man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

> git checkout <commit>
>
> Prepare to work on top of <commit>, by detaching HEAD at it (see "DETACHED HEAD" section), and updating the index and the files in the
>   working tree. **Local modifications to the files in the working tree are
>   kept, so that the resulting working tree will be the state recorded in
>   the commit plus the local modifications**.
>
> Passing --detach forces this behavior in the case of a  (without the option, giving a branch name to the command would check
>   out the branch, instead of detaching HEAD at it), or the current
>   commit, if no  is specified.

If you want to discard your changes, [`git reset`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) is what you are looking for. To actually see some difference in branches, create a new branch from master, make some changes to files, and **commit your changes**. After that, checking out between master and your new branch will produce the results that you are expecting.

Comment: The `<commit>` applies also to `master`?

Comment: No. That's a different case. Check the man pages for difference of `git checkout <commit>` and `git checkout <branch>`

Answer (score 1):

Git prevents you from losing your changes. If you want to checkout another branch you should either commit or stash your changes first. If you want to discard your changed you can do so with `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your described workflow, you don't need to checkout `master`; you're still on it.

After you make edits and commit your work, assuming you have a clean working directory (check with `git status`), you are now at the "tip" (HEAD) of the `master` branch.

The reason you still see your modifications is that you have a dirty working directory; i.e. you've made changes to a file (or files) that are tracked (i.e. have been added to the index or committed).

You only need to check out a different branch if you don't want to do work on `master`, which appears to be the branch you're on.